# Swapping two boost::adjacency_list graphs, akin to std::swap

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, stl, boost-graph

I'm building an application, which contains a class `DecoratedGraph` (say) making use of a `boost::adjacency_list` `graph` as an underlying member.

I have a bunch of other members in `DecoratedGraph` too, some of them storing `std::map` and `std::vector` on `vertices` of the `graph`, representing various additional properties. I will refer to these additional properties as `decorations`.

I have written a custom copy constructor, which would not only copy the graph but make sure that the `decorations` refer to the vertices on the ***copied*** graph, not the original graph.

According to the [Rule of 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)), alongside the copy constructor, we also need a definition for the copy assignment operator and a destructor - and so I have been implementing these also.

For the copy assignment operator, I've made use of the copy-and-swap idiom, suggested by [another stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom). To implement a swap function for my class, I would need to swap both the `graph` and the `decorations`. For now, I have used `std::map::swap` and `std::vector::swap` to swap the `decorations`, and used `std::swap` to swap the other members of the two objects, including the `graph`.

However, when trying to make use of the `decorations` on my swapped object, I found that the references no longer refer to the vertices on the `graph`. I'm not certain where I have gone wrong: I believe the problem most likely lies in the `swap` function not behaving as I had expected. The `swap`s used on the `deocrations` are the member methods for `std::map` and `std::vector` respectively - I would expect these to function as expected. The one place that I suspect may be a problem is the usage of `std::swap` on `boost::adjacency_list` objects, which perhaps will have unexpected behaviour.

I'm wondering if `std::swap` is the correct way to go about swapping two `boost::adjacency_list` `graph`s? If not, what would be the correct approach?

Comment: Everything depends on how you tie the decorations and the descriptors together. What's your graph type, and your `DecoratedGraph` type actually like?

Comment: I posted a general answer. To clarify: depeending on your choice of graph model and property mappings copy semantics **could** result in correct behaviour on copy, but I'm assuming that your issue is because of e.g. using a node-based `VertexList` container selector or other mapping ids that are not stable on move/copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, `std::swap` doesn't seem to be what you want. It selects [the generic `std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)  that moves through a temporary, very simplified implementation:

```
template <typename T> inline void swap(T& a, T& b) {
    T tmp = std::move(a);
    a = std::move(b);
    b = std::move(tmp);
}
```

This would seem fine, except that Boost Graph largely predates C++11 so doesn't *actuvely* use move semantics. This is exemplified by the implementation of `adjacency_list<>::swap` member:

```
void swap(adjacency_list& x)
{
    // Is there a more efficient way to do this?
    adjacency_list tmp(x);
    x = *this;
    *this = tmp;
}
```

They don't even pretend to try to move.

### What To Do

Depending on how you catered for your decorations, you might get a free home-run using [copy_graph](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/graph/doc/copy_graph.html), which will copy internal properties as well as bundled properties and graph properties.

You will want to manually replicate external [property maps](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/graph/doc/using_property_maps.html) (or your home-grown equivalent of it).

### Out-Of-The Box

The conventional way to make swap both cheap **and** atomic (think about exception safety!) is to use Pimpl idiom and just swap the implementation pointers.

Comment: Thank you. I had a read and I think the `Pimpl` idiom would suit my use case best. Surprised (and disappointed!) that was in `boost`'s actual source code!

Comment: Note that BGL is highly (highly) generic, so you *can* have stable descriptors but it might not suit your other access patterns as well. Basically, you're simply trading off what to optimize: optimize for cheap move/swap or optimize for some other use case.